# How do I loop an image carousel with React setState and setInterval?

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am trying to set up an image carousel that loops through 3 images when you mouseover a div. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to reset the loop after it reaches the third image. I need to reset the setInterval so it starts again and continuously loops through the images when you are hovering over the div. Then when you mouseout of the div, the loop needs to stop and reset to the initial state of 0. Here is the Code Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lake-wn3s7

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { images } from "./Data";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let timer;
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  const updateCount = () => {
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
    }, 1000);

    if (count === 3) clearInterval(timer);
  };

  const origCount = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
    setCount((count) => 0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="title">Image Rotate</div>
      <div onMouseOver={updateCount} onMouseOut={origCount}>
        <img src={images[count].source} alt={images.name} />
        <p>count is: {count}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything involving timers/intervals is an excellent candidate for [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), because we can easily register a clear action in the same place that we set the timer using [effects with cleanup](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup). This avoids the common pitfalls of forgetting to clear an interval, e.g. when the component unmounts, or losing track of interval handles. Try something like the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { images } from "./Data";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [mousedOver, setMousedOver] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set an interval timer if we are currently moused over
    if (mousedOver) {
      const timer = setInterval(() => {
        // cycle prevCount using mod instead of checking for hard-coded length
        setCount((prevCount) => (prevCount + 1) % images.length);
      }, 1000);
      // automatically clear timer the next time this effect is fired or
      // the component is unmounted
      return () => clearInterval(timer);
    } else {
      // otherwise (not moused over), reset the counter
      setCount(0);
    }
    // the dependency on mousedOver means that this effect is fired
    // every time mousedOver changes
  }, [mousedOver]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="title">Image Rotate</div>
      <div
        // just set mousedOver here instead of calling update/origCount
        onMouseOver={() => setMousedOver(true)}
        onMouseOut={() => setMousedOver(false)}
      >
        <img src={images[count].source} alt={images.name} />
        <p>count is: {count}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit hungry-einstein-d8pe0]

As to why your code didn't work, a few things:

1. You meant to say `if (count === 2) ...`, not `count === 3`. Even better would be to use the length of the `images` array instead of hardcoding it
2. Moreover, the value of `count` was [stale inside of the closure](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/), i.e. after you updated it using `setCount`, the old value of `count` was still captured inside of `updateCount`. This is actually the reason to use functional state updates, which you did when you said e.g. `setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1)`
3. You would have needed to loop the count inside the interval, not clear the interval on mouse over. If you think through the logic of it carefully, this should hopefully be obvious
4. In general in react, using a function local variable like `timer` is not going to do what you expect. Always use state and effects, and in rarer cases (not this one), some of the other hooks like [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Answer (score 1):

Your `setCount` should use a condition to check to see if it should go back to the start:

```
setCount((prevCount) => prevCount === images.length - 1 ? 0 : prevCount + 1);
```

This will do `setCount(0)` if we're on the last image—otherwise, it will do `setCount(prevCount + 1)`.

A faster (and potentially more readable) way of doing this would be:

```
setCount((prevCount) => (prevCount + 1) % images.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. The timer reference is reset each render cycle, store it in a React ref so it persists.
2. The initial `count` state is closed over in interval callback scope.
3. There are only 3 images so the last slide will be index 2, not 3. You should compare against the length of the array instead of hard coding it.
4. You can just compute the image index by taking the modulus of `count` state by the array length.

Code:

```
export default function App() {
  const timerRef = useRef();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  // clear any running intervals when unmounting
  useEffect(() => () => clearInterval(timerRef.current), []);

  const updateCount = () => {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCount((count) =>  count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  };

  const origCount = () => {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
    setCount(0);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="title">Image Rotate</div>
      <div onMouseOver={updateCount} onMouseOut={origCount}>
        <img
          src={images[count % images.length].source} // <-- computed index to cycle
          alt={images.name}
        />
        <p>count is: {count}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-do-i-loop-an-image-carousel-with-react-setstate-and-setinterval]

Comment: This fails to clear an active interval when the component unmounts. Obviously moot at the top level, but in a reusable component that might come and go, the interval keeps firing after unmount. See [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-do-i-loop-an-image-carousel-with-react-setstate-and-setinterval-forked-0tgdq?file=/src/App.js) for an example. `useEffect` to clean up the interval is the better approach.

Comment: @thisisrandy Question/issue wasn't really about that, but you're not incorrect. Cleaning up running timers is an extremely trivial matter.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `setInterval` does not work well with function components. Since callback accesses variables through closure, it's really easy to shoot own foot and either get timer callback referring to stale values or even have multiple intervals running concurrently. Not telling you cannot overcome that, but using `setTimeout` is much much much easier to use

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(state === 3) return;
  const timerId = setTimeout(() => setState(old => old + 1), 5000);
  return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
}, [state]);
```

Maybe in this particular case cleanup(`clearTimeout`) is not required, but for example if user is able to switch images manually, we'd like to delay next auto-change.