# Using the state function in another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using useState to render the list of recipes based on the API call. i want to pass the setRecipeList function created in RecipeList component in the App.js component to render the list of recipes based on the response

```
RecipeList.js

    import React, { useState } from "react";
import Recipe from "./Recipe";
import styles from "./RecipeList.module.css";
const RecipeList = (props) => {
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([]);
  setRecipeList();
  return (
    <div className={styles.recipe_list}>
      {recipeList.length &&
        recipeList.map((recipeObj) => (<Recipe recipeObj={recipeObj} />))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RecipeList;

App.js

import React, { useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import Header from "./Components/Header";
import RecipeList from "./Components/RecipeList";


function App() {
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState();

  const fetchRecipe = async (searchString) => {
    const response = await Axios.get(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchString}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    );
    console.log(response);
  };
  const onTextChangeHandler = (e) => {
    //debouncing - to skip API calls for initial letters when entering the input
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => fetchRecipe(e.target.value), 500);
    setTimeoutId(timeout);
  };
  return (
    <>
    <Header onTextChange = {onTextChangeHandler} />
    <RecipeList/>
    </ >
  );
}

export default App;
```

link for the complete code  - https://github.com/Moulya27/Recipe-Finder

Comment: Instead of creating a state Variable inside the child component declare the state variable inside the parent and then pass it child.... So in child and parent both have acces to the variable !

Comment: Please remove your API key from your code! I doubt you want to be sharing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to pass data downstream, i.e. from `App` to `RecipeList`, you need to use [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). Rather than declaring `recipeList` and `setRecipeList` in `RecipeList`, you could instead declare them in `App`, use `setRecipeList` inside `fetchRecipe`, and pass `recipeList` as a prop to `RecipeList`, where it can consume the data as it changes. Something like the following:

```
function App() {
  ...
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([]);
  const fetchRecipe = async (searchString) => {
    const response = await Axios.get(
      `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${searchString}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
    );
    setRecipeList(response);
  };
  ...
  return (
    <>
      <Header onTextChange={onTextChangeHandler} />
      <RecipeList { ...recipeList } />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
const RecipeList = ({recipeList}) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.recipe_list}>
      {recipeList.length &&
        recipeList.map((recipeObj) => (<Recipe recipeObj={recipeObj} />))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Notice how I've used [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) to feed `recipeList` to `RecipeList` and [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull `recipeList` directly out of `RecipeList`'s `props`. I could also have said `<RecipeList recipeList={recipeList} />` and `(props) => ... props.recipeList ...`.

In general, the idiom in react is to create state at higher levels and pass either the state variable (`recipeList`), the setter function (`setRecipeList`), or both down to lower levels to suit your purpose. This can get unwieldy, however. Other options include [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) and [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/), which allow more fine-grained control.

Finally, as Yoshi also mentions, anything with timers should be dealt with using [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). Here's a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69485488/12162258) of mine that demonstrates how and why.

Comment: Thank you! it worked

Answer (score 0):

if you want a simple solution with useState, then I'd recommend to shift the useState to the App.js and pass the setRecipeList down into the RecipeList.js component.

```
RecipeList.js

...
const RecipeList = (props) => {
const { recipeList, setRecipeList } = props;

...


App.js

...
function App() {
  const [timeoutId, setTimeoutId] = useState();
  const [recipeList, setRecipeList] = useState([]);

  ...

 return (
   <>
     <Header onTextChange = {onTextChangeHandler} />
     <RecipeList recipeList={recipeList} setRecipeList={setRecipeList} />
   </ >
  );
}

export default App;
```

I didn't get much what you do with the setRecipeList in the recipe component but definitely it is good to wrap the fetch data into useEffectHook.
Good luck!:)